# Java: Loop that has a user enter integers not totaling the entries correctly

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I need to write a program that asks for integers and loops until the input is a negative integer, when the program will then end. Additionally, the loop needs to count the total number of positive integer entries and add all of the entries together. The count portion of the code seems to work fine, but my approach to getting the sum of all entries is NOT working.

What I have tried in my code is to put total=total+input at the end of my loop, but this isn't giving the correct sum when tested.

Additionally, my type safe block only works for the first entry; if I enter a letter after an integer, it crashes the program. Shouldn't that loop back to the type safe block at the beginning of each entry?

I pasted a copy of my output at the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    int count   =   0;
    int total   =   0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print( "Enter an integer, negative to quit: " );

    while(!scan.hasNextInt())
            {
                scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println( "That is not an integer." );
                System.out.println( "Please enter an integer." );
            }

    int input = scan.nextInt();

    while (input >= 0)
        {
            System.out.print( "Next integer: " );

            input = scan.nextInt();

            count++;
            total   =   total + input;
        }

    System.out.println( "Count: " + count ); 
    System.out.println( "Total: " + total );
```

When I run my code, I get the following output:

run:

Enter an integer, negative to quit: h

That is not an integer.

Please enter an integer:

1

Next integer: 2

Next integer: 3

Next integer: -1

Count: 3

Total: 4

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)

Comment: Try to use only one loop, it would make things simpler. Perhaps always read the whole line to a string that you try to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check on each iteration if the next entry is an `integer` or not. Aditionally you need to sum the initial `integer` before you ask for the next one:

```
int input = 0;
int count = 0;
int total = 0;
do{
    System.out.print("Enter an Integer: ");
    total += input;
    if(!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println( "That is not an integer." );
        input = 0;
     } else {
         input = scan.nextInt();
         count++;
     }
 } while(input >= 0);

System.out.println("Count: " + (count - 1));
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Comment: Thank you, I added an if/else in my while loop and that fixed my issue of later inputs not being checked.

Comment: @StaceyM glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Swap the order of operations. *First* sum and count, *then* get a new input:

```
while (input >= 0) {
    total = total + input;
    count++;

    System.out.print("Next integer: ");
    input = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Your current code discards the *first* input `1` and starts summing and counting with the *second*  input `2`.

Comment: And that second input may also be negative

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the order and that solved my total issue.